# Redirecting problem with my php shop code

Tags: php

I've a online shop shawimart.com, the problem with this is that I want the page to be still (not redirect to cart) after I hit add to cart button. but it redirects me to the cart page on every hit on add to cart code is here how can I stop redirecting.

```
<?php if (!empty($input_form_suffix)) {
    $input_form_suffix = '_' . $input_form_suffix;
} ?>

<?php if ($product->listing_type == 'sell_on_site'): ?>
        <?php echo form_open(lang_base_url() . 'add-to-cart', ['id' => 'form_add_cart' . $input_form_suffix]);?>
    <?php $this->load->view('product/details/_product_variations', ['input_id_suffix' => $input_id_suffix]); ?>
    <?php if ($product->is_sold == 0): ?>
        <?php if ($product->quantity > 1 && $product->product_type == 'physical'): ?>
            <div class="row-custom">
                <label class="lbl-quantity"><?php echo trans(""); ?></label>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $this->load->view('product/details/_messages'); ?>

        <?php if ($product->is_free_product != 1): ?>
            <div class="row-custom m-t-15">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity" value="1">
                <button class="btn btn-md btn-block"><?php echo trans("add_to_cart") ?></button>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Where can you please specify.

Comment: this code is strange, I can not help you.

Comment: Is there JavaScript code associated with this? If clicking that button should add to the cart, where is that button's click handler defined?

Comment: Oh man i just noticed this too, you don't have to encapsulate every line with `<?php` `?>`. You can just start a block of php code with `<?php` that spans as many lines of PHP code as you want, closed with `?>`.

Comment: yes i know that, but what about the redirecting problem how can I stop that, stay on same page and products get added to cart..

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX

Comment: how should i add

Comment: If you don't know about AJAX you need to study some tutorials

Comment: can you please add the ajax line in this code, please.

Comment: It's not as simple as just adding a line. And you wouldn't understand the code anyway even if someone wrote it for you, so got wouldn't be able to adapt and update it when needed. Lean properly how Ajax works, and then apply the principles you learn to your own requirements. Just like the way you learn anything in programming. Try it out. If you get stuck with your attempt, ask a more specific question about your code on this site.